# Sum values for similar lines using awk

Tags: awk

From the example below I want to sum the scores for the rows where `Targets` and `miRNA` are similar: Please see below.

```
 Target       miRNA                 Score
 NM_198900    hsa-miR-423-5p       -0.244
 NM_198900    hsa-miR-423-5p       -0.6112
 NM_1989230   hsa-miR-413-5p       -0.644
 NM_1989230   hsa-miR-413-5p       -0.912
```

Output:

```
NM_198900      hsa-miR-423-5p       -0.8552
NM_1989230     hsa-miR-413-5p       -1.556
```

Comment: Is your file sorted? Is it ok to sort it?

Comment: you can sort it, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '{x[$1 " " $2]+=$3} END{for (r in x)print r,x[r]}' file
```

As it sees each line, it adds the third field (`$3`) into an array `x[]` as indexed by joining fields 1 and 2 with a space between them. At the end, it prints all elements of `x[]`.

Following @jaypal's suggestion, you may prefer this which retains your header line (NR==1) and uses TABs as the Output Field Separator

```
awk 'NR==1{OFS="\t";print;next} {x[$1 OFS $2]+=$3} END{for (r in x)print r,x[r]}' file
```

Comment: +1: You probably want to print the header line as is and start the addition from second line onwards. Also, setting the `SUBSEP` variable to `FS` allows you to use cleaner form of composite keys `x[$1,$2]`.

Comment: @jaypal: Yes, thank you. I have amended accordingly.